# Strange “Last Login” ip SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, root

I was told to post this here instaed of StackOverflow so here it goes:

2 weeks ago I accessed my server via SSH and noticed that PuTTY displayed an "Last Login" IP from India. Today I accessed the server again and it showed another IP but from USA. I have noticed that cronjob has been running randomly from time to time.

I went ahead and changed the password but I am paranoid that someone still has access to the server. Is there anything else that I can do besides changing the password?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned cronjob running randomly; have you checked the cronjobs with `crontab -l` for anything unusual? Is the account that was compromised the root account? Even if it isn't, have you checked the last logins and cron entries for the root account as well, if you have root access?

I've seen [dictionary attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) from IP addresses throughout the world on a regular basis to an SSH server I manage. If you are using password authentication and don't use a [strong password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength), someone may guess your new password, also.

If you control the server, i.e., you have root access, if you know you will only need to connect to the server using SSH from a limited number or range of IP addresses, create a firewall rule to only allow SSH access from the IP addresses from which you need to connect.

At this point, if the attacker may have gained root access, it may be difficult to eliminate the possibility that the attacker hasn't installed some software to permit himself access by other means as well, possibly by modifying system files, so the safest course would be to reinstall the operating system and all applications you need. If that's not feasible, can you control and monitor access to the system from a point external to the system, e.g., a firewall in front of the server?

Also see the Server Fault question [How do I know if my Linux server has been hacked?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2783/how-do-i-know-if-my-linux-server-has-been-hacked) for suggestions on actions you can take. E.g., Ian Purton's suggestion to use the command `find /etc /var -mtime -2` to see if files have been changed in the last two days in those directories. Substitute an appropriate number of days for `-2`. You could also run [chkrootkit](http://www.chkrootkit.org/) as someone else suggested.

If you are using firewall software that allows you to specify a [fqdn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) in addition to IP addresses for firewall rules, you could specify that you want to allow access from something like muki.mydomain.com and then use a [DDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) service, such as [No-IP](http://no-ip.com), so that any new IP address would be associated with muki.mydomain.com. No-IP offers a free service level where you use one of their domains, but could specify something like muki.noipdomain.com for your host. You then install software on the system that you use for the SSH client that periodically reports its IP address to No-IP DNS servers. Those servers will then translate muki.mydomain.com or muki.noipdomain.com to whatever current IP address is assigned to the system from which you are trying to establish the SSH connection.

Or you can control access by [public/private keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), instead of passwords. I.e., someone can only login to an account on the SSH server, if they have a private key that corresponds to the public key for the account on the server. If password authentication is disabled and access is restricted by public/private keys instead, then password guessing won't work. Only someone who has the private key corresponding to the public key for an account on the server can login to that account via SSH. I don't use WHM, but there's an article [WHM / cPanel : SSH with Root Login disabled](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/ssh-root-login-disabled.html) on how to do that using WHM.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. I have limited knowledge when it comes to server security. I haven't noticed anything unusual in crontab besides what was already there. What I think might have been changed is the timezone from UTC to EDT but I am not sure. The problem with the cronjob is that the cronjob is supposed to run once every 24 hours but sometimes it runs at random time + the once every 24 hours.

I was thinking about limiting the SSH access to only my IP but what happens if I change my IP in the future, how am I supposed to access the server? Also, will this affect WHM root login?

Comment: @Muki, I added a reference to a Server Fault posting with some other suggestions of actions you could take and a response to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user account.

Password 8+ digits 1+ upper, 1+ lower 1+symbol and 1+ special character.

Use iptables and/or ipset to block ip's you won't be coming from, or create allow rules for ip's with CIDR you will be coming from.

install and configure fail2ban in case they try and brute force you.